# Cursor disappears behind soft keyboard when typing in textarea on iOS mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

Suppose I have a high textarea, like this:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="200"></textarea>
```

such as the one in https://jsbin.com/jevipuz.

When I open this site in mobile Safari or Chrome on iOS and I start typing in the textarea, the text disappears behind the soft keyboard after a while, because the body doesn't scroll to keep the cursor in view. It works correctly on Android mobile browsers (and desktop browsers).

Is there a way to make this work on iOS as well, using HTML, CSS and/or JS?

Comment: Did you try to set `overflow-y: scroll;` for that `textarea`?

Comment: Can you post your code? The default action is to move the entire page up so the bottom of the input is above Keyboard. It sounds like you have something preventing that from happening correctly.

Comment: @JaredChu: no, because I don't want the textarea itself to scroll.

Comment: @BryceHowitson: the sample above is basically all of the code. It is directly inside the <body> of a blank html page. No CSS, no Javascript. You can try it by loading the sample jsbin on an iPhone.